# ¿Es correcto crear una columna de folio y administrarla dentro de una aplicación web?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Me propusieron crear una tabla folios con los siguientes campos (disculpen mi intento de pseudocodigo):

```
tabla_folios [
      dependecia id char,   
      subdependencia id char,
      operacion id char,
      aplicacion id varchar,
      annio id varchar, 
      folio int
]
```

Y administrar los folios con algo como esto:

```
select (max(folio)+1) as folioNuevo from tabla_folios 
where aplicacion=? and operacion=? and dependencia=? and subdependencia=?
```

Y despues actualizar el incremento del folio con un update:

```
update tabla_folios set folio=folioNuevo 
where aplicacion=? and operacion=? and dependencia=? and subdependencia=?
```

Lo cual no me parece del todo seguro por la concurrencia. **¿Es correcto hacer esto o existen mejores estrategias?** Al parecer lo quieren hacer así para reiniciar el folio cada año, pero yo quitaría la columna annio y el folio lo volvería bigint para jamas reiniciarlo.

Cabe mencionar que los folios se recuperarían de esta tabla para obtener un consecutivo para otra tabla.

¿Las funcionalides de SMBD afectan en este tipo de implementación? es para sql server.

Comment: Lo mejor es que uses un campo autonumerico en SQL Server, con eso te evitas actualizar el contador y la concurrencia. Saludos,

Comment: ¿Y como obtengo un folio para cada combinación de los campos llave con un autonumerico? `tabla_folios[dependecia id char, subdependencia id char,operacion id char,aplicacion id varchar,annio id varchar,folio int]`Lo pregunto porque necesitaria insertar para que funcione el autonomerico, pero esta tabla ya esta llena de registros con el folio en ceros para cada fila.

Answer (score 1):

Sin duda, el folio deberá ser un autonumérico, pero adicional a eso yo prefiero que en la tabla `tabla_folios` se genere una llave compuesta, las principales ventajas serían:

- Los números de folio estarán disponibles por cada elemento de la llave compuesta.
- Mitigas el problema de concurrencia.

A modo de ejemplo, te propondría la generación de una llave compuesta por `DependeciaId`, `SubdependenciaId`, `OperacionId`, `Folio`, además de que los `Ids` deben ser numéricos. Si por cualquier razón es necesario que sean una cadena de caracteres solo debes tomar este ejemplo con un `VARCHAR`:

```
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
| DependeciaId | SubdependenciaId | OperacionId | Folio |
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 1            | 1                | 1           | 1     |
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 1            | 1                | 1           | 2     |
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 2            | 1                | 1           | 1     | <-- El número de folio se repite, pero al ser una llave compuesta no marca ningún error
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 2            | 1                | 1           | 2     | <-- De igual forma aquí, pero el campo DependenciaId cambia
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 2            | 2                | 1           | 1     | <-- Aquí se repite el Folio y DependenciaId, pero cambia SubDependenciaId, por lo tanto ya no causa conflicto
+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------+
```

## Actualización

He creado un pequeño ejercicio, donde demuestro que no es necesario calcular el `Folio`, ya que para cada `INSERT` se va autoincrementando, por lo tanto, ya no es necesario hacer el `UPDATE`. Espero que este caso demostrativo te sea de utilidad.

<kbd>[Demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/JJHPFM30903)</kbd>

Comment: Si entiendo, aunque creo que entendiste mal un poco, por eso puse (disculpen mi seudocodigo). Puse `Ids` para indicar que esos eran los campos llave de la tabla. Esta es exactamente la idea que se tiene, la que propones. Pero en esta idea no me parece muy seguro esto: `select (max(folio)+1) as folioNuevo from tabla_folios 
where aplicacion=? and operacion=? and dependencia=? and subdependencia=?` Porque pueden llegar dos peticiones al mismo tiempo a hacer max con la misma llave compuesta. Es por eso mi pregunta.

Comment: @abrahamhs Yo propuse esta forma dado que aún no me queda claro para que se necesita el `UPDATE`, ya que puedes ingresar un número de folio desde el INSERT y que sea de tipo `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` para que independientemente de quién lo inserte siempre sea un auto incrementable y no tengas información repetida o que te marque error :)

Comment: @abrahamhs he actualizado mi respuesta, espero que esto te sea de mayor utilidad.

Comment: Al parecer, el necesita que no haya "saltos" de secuencia de folios entre un mismo registro de dependenciaId, subdependenciaId y operacionId, por esa razón no le sirve el autoincremental.

Comment: Exacto, es como comenta `CharlieBits`. Como comentas `Fxltr` el folio es el mismo para todas las llaves, por lo que hay salto en las llaves. Pero lo que quiero es exactamente como comenta `CharlieBits`, pero no se me hace muy seguro hacer el select y luego el update por la concurrencia, Por eso mi pregunta ¿Esta es la mejor alternativa?

Comment: @abrahamhs de hecho era lo quería expresar, primero sin saltos y calculando el folio y luego con un auto incrementable, dame oportunidad de corregir mi respuesta para poder explicarlo de diferente manera

Answer (score 0):

No me parece mala la estrategia que propones. El autonumérico no funcionará para este caso y dejar al año como parte de la clave para reiniciar el folio cada año no me parece mal tampoco. Tener en cuenta que en el select que estas mostrando falta el año en el where.
El único tema aqui es el problema de duplicación de folios por concurrencia, pero eso es realmente muy sencillo de controlar desde el código de programación (de Java por ejemplo). De manera que creo que tu decisión se debe inclinar por esta solución tranquilamente siempre que estés usando un lenguaje de programación que te permita el control de concurrencia fácilmente.

Comment: El problema que yo veo a lo del año es que cada cambio de año hay que estar repoblando la tabla para el nuevo año y eso es lo que no quiero,. Se supone que un sistema debe ser `autónomo` y no esperar que alguien siempre este detrás `moviendole los hilos` para que funcione. Es decir un sistema debe funcionar aunque el programador se vaya de vacaciones, es mi opinion. Lo del año lo agregue así: `select (max(folio)+1) as folioNuevo from tabla_folios 
where aplicacion=? and operacion=? and dependencia=? and subdependencia=? and ejercicio=YEAR(GETDATE())` con el problema de rellenar la tabla

Comment: Como no conozco el uso de la tabla en el sistema, supuse que los datos ingresan por aplicación. En el caso que planteas estoy completamente de acuerdo con que no se deben implementar soluciones que necesiten al desarrollador encima todo el tiempo. De manera que el año debe quedar fuera de la clave como mejor práctica (o bien poblarse cada principio de año con un job de base de datos, cosa que tampoco recomiendo).